# Database Queries with respect to existing data

Tags: sql, oracle10g

How to check for existing data in a sequel database? I forgot my table name.
Any help or suggestion will be appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: This is a super vague question, one has to ask if you have forgotten the name of the table, do you remember the connectionstring to the database?

Answer (score 0):

Use a freeware management tool like [Toad](http://www.toadworld.com/m/freeware/43) to visually inspect the tables and rows of your database.

Comment: I forgot my table name.Thanks for the advice